# WCF Passing windows credentials of client

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-security, wcf-client

I am creating a WCF service. The service should be able to retrieve the windows identity of the client. How should I configure the service and how should I get the identity of the client connected?

Comment: What kind of client is being used to call into the WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure the BindingConfiguration on the endpoints of both the WCF Service and WCF client to use the same TransportClientCredential -- setting it either to Windows or Ntlm.  In the WCF configuration of the client you will need to establish a new client endpoint configuration for the target server endpoint and assoicate it with the BindingConfiguration which specifies the use of the TransportClientCredential.

I recommend leveraging the WCF Service Configuration Editor to make all of your configuration changes.  Hand editing the app.config and/or web.config files to make WCF configuration changes is very prone to user error and can lead to significant frustration.  The tool makes things MUCH EASIER.

There is a decent (slightly dated for .NET 3.5 but still relevant) example in doing this using a service hosted in IIS with a basicHttpBinding: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFBasicHttpBinding.aspx

If this does not answer your question or you need more detail, please post more specifics and we will be happy to help.